# Problems with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a Binary Search Tree that I'm making and I implemented the Insert node code as follows:

```
BSTNode * BST::Insert(const std::string & v){
    BSTNode * node = new BSTNode(v);
    if (root == NULL){
        root = node;
    } else if (root->value.compare(v) > 0) {
        Insert(root->left, node);
        //recursive insert the method
    } else if (root->value.compare(v) < 0) {
        Insert(root->right, node);
    } else {
        delete node;
        return NULL;
    }
    size++;
    return node;
}
```

Followed by the recursive insert method in my header file (it has private access):

```
void Insert(BSTNode* current, BSTNode* node){
    if (current == NULL){
        current = node;
    } else if (current->value == node->value){
        delete node;
    } else if (current->value < node->value) {
        Insert(current->left, node);
    } else if (current->value > node->value){//if (parent->value < node->value) {
        Insert(current->right, node);
    }
}
```

When the recursive function sets the pointer and then returns, the changes I made to the pointer DON'T stay.

Comment: As a side note, you should never, ever, ever have actual function or method declarations in your header file.  Those should always, always, always be in a .c, not a .h.

Comment: @KeithIrwin: That's not true at all. You just need to `inline` them if you're going to do it. It's still only a good idea for special cases or templates though.

Comment: @KeithIrwin : If I could downvote your comment, I would. :-/

Comment: "I'm sure theres tons of them" So am I. Did you look at any of them?

Comment: @Keith: Who writes C++ in `.c` files? And in C++ there are quite often good reasons to write functions in headers. For non-`template` functions I would agree, but your advice is misleadingly (and incorrectly) generalised.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes I did. :) But like I explained, I didn't know what was causing the problem and I'm not allowed to use boost (which is what most other questions solutions referred to that I saw) But thanks for clarifying my question. I can't type straight when I'm frustrated.

Comment: @Tomalak: Right .cpp, not .c.  It was just a thoughtless error.  As for the others, yes, there are rare but applicable good reasons to put code in a .h.  But the vast majority of the time, it's a bad idea because it'll cause linking errors (or more subtle ones if your dependencies aren't right in your build process and you change the code in your inline function and two different .o files are using two different versions of the function), and even when it doesn't cause linking errors, it still makes the code harder to find because people rarely look for it in header files.

Comment: So, yes, there are rare exceptions, but a new programmer should first get in the habit of not putting any code in header files and then eventually, as they become more experienced, they'll understand when it's okay.

Comment: @KeithIrwin : _That_ I can agree with. :-]

Comment: @Bob: Why are you not "allowed" to use Boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `current` is a local variable with a copy of the value of the pointer.  It's not the same variable that you pass in.  If you want to modify the pointer in place, your method should accept either a pointer to the pointer or a reference to the pointer.  The easiest way to do this would be to just modify `current` to be a reference to a pointer.  The resultant code would look like this:

```
void Insert(BSTNode* &current, BSTNode* node){
    if (current == NULL){
        current = node;
    } else if (current->value == node->value){
        delete node;
    } else if (current->value < node->value) {
        Insert(current->left, node);
    } else if (current->value > node->value){//if (parent->value < node->value) {
        Insert(current->right, node);
    }
}
```

In general, you should keep in mind that pointers are just values which tell you the memory location of something.  So they're really just numbers.  And when they're passed into a function, unless there's a reference, they're passed by the value.  So your function just sees the number, not the variable which contained the number.

Comment: Aahhh!! I didn't think that the compiler would copy the pointer and then send it to the function. Ooohh... So then, I should be able to just declare the function prototype in the private section of my header file and the I can still write the function inside my cpp file then?

Comment: Yes. Prototypes should go in the header and implementation goes in the .cpp file. That way, the header can be included in multiple files which need to use the same classes without the code getting compiled into both (which will generate linker errors). What's happening is that any include directive literally copies everything from the .h into your .cpp file. If the same .h is copied into two different .cpp files, then that code is included twice. When a function or method implementation is included in two different .o files, the linker gives an error because it doesn't know if they're the same

Answer (score 1):

```
void Insert(BSTNode*& current, BSTNode* node)
```

is the correct prototype for the function given. Nothing else need be changed. The reason why this is necessary is described well by Keith.

I would also add that in general you should be wary of conditionally deleting pointers passed as arguments to a function -- you're placing a burden on the code outside that function to determine whether the memory address it refers to is still valid or not. Consider use of boost's shared_ptr instead.

Comment: Sadly since its a school project, I'm not allowed to use boost or anything in the C++ Standard Library except `string` ... but if you know of a better way without boost I'm all ears! :)